# Collapsing navbar closes automaticaly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, toggle, nav

I'm making a site with bootstrap theme ([Darkly](https://bootswatch.com/darkly/)),  but the media screen toggle closes automatically when I try to open it. You can check it [here in the site](http://www.xzone.gr)

Can you help?

Comment: where's that media screen, can u attach a screenshot

Comment: Just small the browser window to show the toggler